# New Navigation z-index issue

Tags: bug, status-declined, new-nav

Please have a look at the following image of SO captured.

Browser is Google Chrome.

[image: alt]

Search bar and new nav down arrow with a dropdown menu is overlapping everything.

It should have a low z-index I guess.

[image: alt]

Have a look at an another snippet.

[image: alt]

Below are the steps to reproduce the issue:

1. First click on achievements or inbox.

   [image: alt]
2. Now click on little down arrow.

   [image: alt]
3. Now write java tag in filter box.

   [image: alt]

Comment: Which *version* of Chrome? Looks OK for me in 53.0.2785.116 (64-bit) and now 54.0.2840.98 (64-bit).

Comment: I edited the post and included chrome version.

Comment: Does the issue persist if you Relaunch with the latest update?

Comment: I even restarted google chrome.

Comment: yeah..issue is still there.

Comment: On 54.0.2840.99 m (64-bit), Windows 10 - no repro.

Comment: Do you have any user scripts or add ons running? Try disabling them and refresh.

Comment: yeah...correct.. I installed **Better Stack Exchange** chrome plugin today. By disabling it, everything works fine..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given this is caused by a Chrome plugin, we are not in a position to fix it.